# iPad Air bedtime alarm sample loops indefinitely when stopped after upgrade to iOS 11

Tags: ipad, bug, ios, alarm

After upgrade to iOS 11 my *iPad Air 32GB* (*MD786FD/A*) I've got the following defect: the wake-up signal in the integrated bedtime application **keeps playing** after I touch 'stop' button on the screen or press mechanical 'Home' button to stop it. The **short sample of the melody** (~0,5 sec) is **repeated** in the loop continuously. The only way to stop the sound is to switch off the device or start the playback in another application.

In all iOS versions before 11 the problem was not present. I tried 4 updates of iOS 11 (11.0.1, 11.0.2, 11.0.3, 11.1), but the problem is not yet fixed. I tried rebooting the device, enabling-disabling the wake-up alarm, changing the melody - nothing has helped.

Any ideas how to fix that? Any workarounds possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround is to unplug the IPad over the night. For some strange reason sound looping is not happening, if the power is not supplied during the alarm sound. Software fix is not available so far.

Suggested here: https://discussions.apple.com/message/32517010#message32517010